# the Victorians believed characteristic of Catholicism

Tags: syntax

> The Swallow's persistent evocation of Egypt and its exotic and imaginative landscape is also central to his link with Catholicism. His psychic connection to the warm climes of the Middle East seem to aid his sojourn in the English winter: his imagination allows him to visit there and gain some of its benefits without ever physically making the journey. **Egypt is a version of Catholicism here, as it represents the Oriental spirituality the Victorians believed characteristic of Catholicism.**

[From](https://books.google.cz/books?id=QvChAgAAQBAJ&pg=PR4&lpg=PR4&dq=oscar+wilde+fairy+tales+interpretation+book&source=bl&ots=9opaN9Ngbr&sig=4yXZWydvyfpcm86-fu_M6gNVxfo&hl=cs&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-9qWaxp_cAhUJYJoKHUQaCv04ChDoAQiLATAE#v=onepage&q=oscar%20wilde%20fairy%20tales%20interpretation%20book&f=false) *The Fairy Tales of Oscar Wilde* by Jarlath Killeen (Routledge, 2007).

I am not sure whether I understand the sentence properly. I would add two words: *that* and *is*.

> "Egypt is a version of Catholicism here, as it represents the Oriental spirituality **that** the Victorians believed **is** characteristic of Catholicism."

In the case of *that*, I understand the omission. But why is *is* absent here?

Comment: The phrase can also be "believed **to be** characteristic".

Comment: I'd say the most likely "missing word" is ***was***, not ***is***. But it's perfectly ordinary English as transcribed. [*Socrates claimed that individuals could not knowingly embark on a course of action (that) **they thought unwise** or bad.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+course+of+action+that+they+thought+unwise%22)

Comment: The complement can be an adjective phrase.  *They reported the car stolen. The car believed stolen was taken by their teenage son without their knowledge.*

Comment: It's unclear how "Egypt" can be a version of "Catholicism".   Do you mean the  [*Coptic* Catholic Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_Catholic_Church)?

Comment: @Andrew: In the original, **Egypt is a version of Catholicism** is being used to mean "Egypt stands for|represents Catholicism". It's like saying "In his novels, the American West is freedom".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Ah.  So it's saying that in Oscar Wilde's stories, "Egypt" is a metaphor for Catholicism, as in something like "In Egypt they do X, Y and Z" to figuratively mean, "In Catholicism they do X, Y, and Z"?

Comment: Yep, metaphor for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the sentence is identical to the meaning with the words you added.

Both the omissions are considered perfectly normal and correct.

(It would be more correct to write "believed *to be* characteristic" or "believed *was* characteristic" rather than "believed *is* characteristic", to make the tenses agree.)

Comment: I agree that "to be characteristic" is better, but it's not clear to me what you mean by "to make the tenses agree".  What other verb would it be *agreeing* with?

Comment: 'Believed', in the past tense. If the believing is happening in the past, then the characteristics cannot be in the present. They can be infinitive ("believed to be") or past ("believed was...")

Comment: The verb to agree with is "believed." It is dubious that Victorians had any common belief about what the characteristics of Catholicism would be in the 21st century. British protestants of the late 19th century did generally share beliefs about Catholicism as an historical and contemporary movement.